# How do I download files from the web using the requests module?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to download a webpage data to samplefile.txt on my hard drive using the following code:

```
import requests 
res = requests.get('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112.txt')
res.raise_for_status()
playFile = open('samplefile.txt', 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    playFile.write(chunk)

playFile.close()
```

The code runs without errors but nothing changes in samplefile.txt. How do I fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: Your code works for me!

Comment: You are using a relative file path and so where the file is saved depends entirely on the current working directory of the script as it runs. Use an absolute path instead or print `os.getcwd()` to see what directory you are saving the file to.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
res = requests.get('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1112/pg1112.txt')
res.raise_for_status()
open('samplefile.txt', 'wb').write(res.content)
```

This is file samplefile.txt
"""The Project Gutenberg EBook of Romeo and Juliet, by William Shakespeare
....
"""

Comment: Yes, the code works. The issue is that the OP doesn’t fully understand what the code *does* however. Like where the file is being saved.