# How do I use requests module to download csv file

Tags: python, python-requests, export-to-csv

I am learning Python and its different modules.

Below are my codes which were referred by [How do I download files from the web using the requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204422/how-do-i-download-files-from-the-web-using-the-requests-module).

```
import requests as req
url = "https://github.com/alexhegit/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv"
res = req.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
open('housing.csv', 'wb').write(res.content)

os.popen("housing.csv")
```

It is supposed to get data in following format.

```
longitude,latitude,housing_median_age,total_rooms,total_bedrooms,population,households,median_income,median_house_value,ocean_proximity
-122.23,37.88,41.0,880.0,129.0,322.0,126.0,8.3252,452600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.86,21.0,7099.0,1106.0,2401.0,1138.0,8.3014,358500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.85,52.0,1467.0,190.0,496.0,177.0,7.2574,352100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.85,52.0,1274.0,235.0,558.0,219.0,5.6431,341300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.85,52.0,1627.0,280.0,565.0,259.0,3.8462,342200.0,NEAR BAY
....
```

However, I only got http file.

Is there anyone who could please correct my codes? Why my code could not output the data in csv format?

Any further would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check link in your code, it leads to html file, not csv. Click "View raw" to get access to actual file
[image]

You will get [this link instead](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexhegit/handson-ml2/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the url setting is the link you showed to me. But when I got the file, it is still a html file.

Comment: @Leon it can't be html, since url clearly returns plain text content. recheck it on your side

Comment: thanks for your time and help. Yes. The link I used was url = "https://github.com/alexhegit/handson-ml2/blob/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv". It shoudl be "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexhegit/handson-ml2/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv". I sincerely appreciate your time and help.